# Python Keep row if YYYY present else remove the row

Tags: python, regex, date, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe which has a Date column, I want to remove those row from Date column which doesn't have YYYY (eg, 2018, it can be any year) format.
I had used apply method with regex expression but doesn't work ,

```
df[df.Date.apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'[0-9]{4}', x))]
```

The Date column can have values such as,

```
12/3/2018
March 12, 2018
stackoverflow
Mar 12, 2018
no date text
3/12/2018
```

So here output should be

```
12/3/2018
March 12, 2018
Mar 12, 2018
3/12/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach. Using `pd.to_datetime` with `errors="coerce"`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": ['12/3/2018', 'March 12, 2018', 'stackoverflow', 'Mar 12, 2018', 'no date text', '3/12/2018']})
df["Col1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Col1"], errors="coerce")
df = df[df["Col1"].notnull()]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        Col1
0 2018-12-03
1 2018-03-12
3 2018-03-12
5 2018-03-12
```

*Or if you want to maintain the original data*

```
import pandas as pd

def validateDate(d):
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(d)
        return d
    except:
        return None

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": ['12/3/2018', 'March 12, 2018', 'stackoverflow', 'Mar 12, 2018', 'no date text', '3/12/2018']})
df["Col1"] = df["Col1"].apply(validateDate)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Col1
0       12/3/2018
1  March 12, 2018
3    Mar 12, 2018
5       3/12/2018
```